# FullCalendar-v4 allDay events not rendering

Tags: javascript, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have managed to get my recurring events to show up on the calendar, but my single allDay events will not render and I believe its a field problem.

I've tried making the event's start time an iso date which doesn't seem to matter as my recurring events are being saved as a string.

This is a recurring event and shows up on the calendar

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4af079f91ff532f8fc0385"),
    "daysOfWeek" : [ 
        1, 
        2, 
        3
    ],
    "locationId" : ObjectId("5d28cad23f49646797e05adc"),
    "allDay" : true,
    "start" : "2019-08-07",
    "end" : "2019-08-07",
    "startRecur" : "2019-08-07",
    "endRecur" : "2019-08-31",
    "title" : "Change Bulbs",
    "backgroundColor" : "rgb(87, 87, 244)",
    "source" : null,
    "interval" : "Weekly",
    "category" : "Facility",
    "monday" : true,
    "tuesday" : true,
    "wednesday" : true,
    "completed" : false,
    "frequency" : null,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

this is a single event that showed up in FC-v3 but wont in v4

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4b455e121f726f510f2b5c"),
    "daysOfWeek" : [],
    "batchId" : ObjectId("5d28f52d823083adfc6e8c4d"),
    "locationId" : ObjectId("5d28cad23f49646797e05adc"),
    "end" : null,
    "startRecur" : "",
    "endRecur" : "",
    "allDay" : true,
    "start" : "2019-08-08",
    "title" : "First Transplant",
    "backgroundColor" : "rgb(87, 87, 244)",
    "interval" : "Single Event",
    "category" : "Cultivation",
    "monday" : false,
    "tuesday" : false,
    "wednesday" : false,
    "thursday" : false,
    "friday" : false,
    "saturday" : false,
    "sunday" : false,
    "completed" : false,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

so i made an event with the proper ISO Date and it failed as well

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4b4f9a56114f747c7ddcef"),
    "daysOfWeek" : [],
    "batchId" : ObjectId("5d28f52d823083adfc6e8c4d"),
    "locationId" : ObjectId("5d28cad23f49646797e05adc"),
    "allDay" : true,
    "start" : ISODate("2019-08-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "end" : null,
    "title" : "IMP",
    "backgroundColor" : "rgb(87, 87, 244)",
    "interval" : "Single Event",
    "category" : "Cultivation",
    "monday" : false,
    "tuesday" : false,
    "wednesday" : false,
    "thursday" : false,
    "friday" : false,
    "saturday" : false,
    "sunday" : false,
    "completed" : false,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

comp.ts code

```
createEvent(form) {
        if (form.valid) {
            this.newEvent.category = 'Cultivation';
            this.newEvent.completed = false;
            this.newEvent.allDay = true;
            this.newEvent.locationId = this.selectedLocation._id;
            this.newEvent.batchId = this.selectedBatch._id;
            this.newEvent.start = moment(this.newEvent.start).utc();
            this.newEvent.start.hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0);
            // this.newEvent.source =  null;
            // this.newEvent.daysOfWeek = [];
            if (this.newEvent.interval === 'Single Event') {
                this.newEvent.end = null;
                // this.newEvent.startRecur = '';
                // this.newEvent.endRecur = '';
                this.newEvent.monday = false;
                this.newEvent.tuesday = false;
                this.newEvent.wednesday = false;
                this.newEvent.thursday = false;
                this.newEvent.friday = false;
                this.newEvent.saturday = false;
                this.newEvent.sunday = false;
            }
            // if ( this.newEvent.interval === 'Daily'  || this.newEvent.interval === 'Weekly'){
            // }
            if (this.newEvent.interval === 'Weekly') {
                this.newEvent.startRecur = this.newEvent.start;
                this.newEvent.end = this.newEvent.start;
                this.newEvent.frequency = NaN;
                if (this.newEvent.sunday) {
                    this.newEvent.daysOfWeek.push(0);
                }
                if (this.newEvent.monday) {
                    this.newEvent.daysOfWeek.push(1);
                }
                if (this.newEvent.tuesday) {
                    this.newEvent.daysOfWeek.push(2);
                }
                if (this.newEvent.wednesday) {
                    this.newEvent.daysOfWeek.push(3);
                }
                if (this.newEvent.thursday) {
                    this.newEvent.daysOfWeek.push(4);
                }
                if (this.newEvent.friday) {
                    this.newEvent.daysOfWeek.push(5);
                }
                if (this.newEvent.saturday) {
                    this.newEvent.daysOfWeek.push(6);
                }
            }
...sub to database
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting `"daysOfWeek" : [],` means that you are telling the calendar it cannot show the event on any day of the week. That's why it won't appear.

Simply don't set that option in your code for single events, and it will be fine:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4b455e121f726f510f2b5c"),
    "batchId" : ObjectId("5d28f52d823083adfc6e8c4d"),
    "locationId" : ObjectId("5d28cad23f49646797e05adc"),
    "end" : null,
    "startRecur" : "",
    "endRecur" : "",
    "allDay" : true,
    "start" : "2019-08-08",
    "title" : "First Transplant",
    "backgroundColor" : "rgb(87, 87, 244)",
    "interval" : "Single Event",
    "category" : "Cultivation",
    "monday" : false,
    "tuesday" : false,
    "wednesday" : false,
    "thursday" : false,
    "friday" : false,
    "saturday" : false,
    "sunday" : false,
    "completed" : false,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LwdgeG

P.S. There's nothing wrong with your date string.

Comment: I've copied and pasted the code from above into the database and the event is still not populating.

Comment: Hmm. Without seeing a worked example of exactly what you did, and exactly what data is coming into fullCalendar as a result, then I can't tell you what went wrong. As you can see from my CodePen demo, if you give exactly that data to fullCalendar, without the daysOfWeek property included, then it works properly. The concept is correct, but maybe there is some other fault in your code which means the event is not being sent to the calendar or does not contain the correct properties. I can help, if you can provide a reproducible  full example

Comment: I found that removing the "daysOfWeek" field from the document and the model allowed my single all day events to render properly. Unfortunately, that isn't a solid solution for someone who has this same problem who wants to use recurring events. Because FC doesn't build individual objects for each recurring event, the recurring event feature isn't useful to me and I'll have to populate those manually. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @MVM I'm not really sure I get your point...you can either include the daysOfWeek field, or not, as required in each case. If it's not going to be a recurring event, then don't create that property in your object. It shouldn't be hard to implement that, surely? Or if you prefer you could switch to defining recurring events using RRule, as provided by the [relevant fullCalendar plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin) - maybe that would suit you better somehow? And of course if you have a suggestion to improve this part of fullCalendar, you can always send them a feature request.

Comment: The recurring event feature takes one event from the database and populates the calendar not producing event objects for the other events. Is that incorrect? I need an individual object for each recurring event as I need to mark whether the event is completed, assign the event to a user, and keep track of the beginning and finish time for each event. This information is required for our analytics/ML. Am I wrong about how the calendar works?

Comment: No, you're correct about that. I was just confused because it seemed unrelated to your question, I didn't get why you thought my answer was not a "solid solution". So yes, in your case you will need to create each event individually I believe

Comment: Ahh, I meant my solution  "removing the "daysOfWeek" field from the document and the model" wasn't a solid solution. Thanks for your help.